# I am having trouble making an image resize responsively to its parent element

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and it is very ugly and disorganized but i am trying to pass the last test on a freecodecamp project. https://codepen.io/thomas-nurney/pen/PoZjXyw?editors=1100

```
<img id="boardpic" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7845/46438012904_068fcdaf8b_b.jpg" max-width="100%" width="200" height="200" style=width:100%; border="0" alt="Surfboard shaping"/><fig-caption>Patience is the key to smoothing out the rough edges while shaping a surfboard.</figcaption>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried adding the max-width property to several elements but am not getting past the test.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Please edit your question and paste code here, into this question. This would make your question easier to Google and to be found (and answered) by "the right" person. The better you'll make your question, the easier it gets for someone to answer it and help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img id="boardpic" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7845/46438012904_068fcdaf8b_b.jpg" style="width:100%;height:200px;max-width:100%" alt="Surfboard shaping"/>
```

The height and width need units like 'px','%' etc

And style values have to be in double qoutes like style="...."

Answer (score -1):

try these code snippets I solve it all for you

```
 <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-width:700px){
    
  }
</style>
<nav id="navbar" style="position:fixed;">
 <li><a href="#projects">projects</a></li>
  
 
</nav>
<a id="profile-link" href="https://github.com" target="_blank">github</a>
 <section id="welcome-section" style="height:100vh;overflow:auto;">
   <h1> hi</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="projects">
   <div class="project-tile">
     <a href="#projects"></a>
   </div>
  </section>

<!-- 

Hello Camper!

For now, the test suite only works in Chrome! Please read the README below in the JS Editor before beginning. Feel free to delete this message once you have read it. Good luck and Happy Coding! 

- The freeCodeCamp Team 

-->
```